# Kxstudio installation errors in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, I am trying to install kxstudio. The following message pops out when I try to activate kxstudio-repos-gcc5 via the software center i got the following error pop-up

```
Got unknown content type (null) from reviews.ubuntu.com on ubuntu 17.10
```

and while using the terminal to do the same task using following command

```
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos-gcc5_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb
```

I received the following error

```
Preparing to unpack kxstudio-repos-gcc5_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb ...
Unpacking kxstudio-repos-gcc5 (9.4.6~kxstudio1) over (9.4.6~kxstudio1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kxstudio-repos-gcc5:
 kxstudio-repos-gcc5 depends on kxstudio-repos; however:
  Package kxstudio-repos is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kxstudio-repos-gcc5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kxstudio-repos-gcc5
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Use the repositories rather than downloading .deb

There is a detailed page on how to do this here - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories

And for your missing package:

> All Debian and Ubuntu users can enable our repositories by installing
>   this deb file: [kxstudio-repos.deb](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb)

And instructions

```
# Install required dependencies if needed
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https software-properties-common wget

# Download package file
wget https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb

# Install it
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb
```